# How to combine date and number to form an ID?(php)

Tags: php, html

I want to have and id where the first 8 number is the date (yyyymmdd) and the rest will be the increment of number which will reset every day.

For example:

```
  id
----------
2017301101

2017301102

2017301103

2017011201
```

Note that the id is reset when the date changes. How do I make this possible in php?

Comment: why (on earth) would you want to use an id as a date and in that format? and what's the RDBMS used?

Comment: Last time I checked there wasn't a 30th month.

Comment: I dont know why this question was downvoted

Comment: @sumit not me but downvote buttons are for a question which does not show any research effort (check); it is unclear or not useful (check)..

Comment: I feel bad, here you go @mrblock7777 `echo date('YmdH');` https://3v4l.org/ojuUn

Comment: this is actually to generate invoice id. sorry

Answer (score 0):

To create this id, you use the [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), like this.

```
function generateId($existingIds) {
    $currentDate = date('Ymd');

    $id = 1;

    while (in_array($currentDate . sprintf('%02d', $id),$existingIds)) {
        $id++;
    }

    return $currentDate . sprintf('%02d', $id);
}
```

I use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format the number to always be at least two digits (01, 10, 100). After that I check if the generated id is not yet in the array using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Then you would call this function by supplying the array of existing ids, in a way like this.

```
$idArray = [];
array_push($idArray,generateId($idArray));
```

Here you generate an id and immediately push it to the array.